# The output of TestNG java class on inherited class is confusing

Tags: testng, testng-annotation-test

I have two classes which are specified below

```java
package otherFeatures;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DependsOnInheritedTestMethodExample extends ParentClassExample{

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "myTestE")
    public void myTestA() {
        System.out.println("I am in myTestA");
    }

    @Test
    public void myTestB() {
        System.out.println("I am in myTestB");
    }

}
```

The above class is dependent to below parent class as shown

```java
package otherFeatures;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class ParentClassExample {


    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "myTestF")
    public void myTestE() {

        System.out.println("I am in myTestE");

    }

    @Test
    public void myTestF() {

        System.out.println("I am in myTestF");

    }

}
```

Previosly when i ran this program 2 years back it gave be below result

```
I am in myTestB
I am in myTestF
I am in myTestE
I am in myTestA
```

But now when i run i see below result

```
I am in myTestF
I am in myTestE
I am in myTestB
I am in myTestF
I am in myTestE
I am in myTestA
```

Can someone please let me know why "I am in myTestE" and "I am in myTestA" from current output is repeated in the end again?

Comment: Can someone help me out here . I really need help here.

Comment: Can anyone please help me here ?